# unable to display data to html table from python file

Tags: python, html, for-loop

I am trying to display the data that I am getting from the database, I am having trouble to display them into html table.

store.py

```
def book_list():
    # Define the query for the DB
      query = "SELECT * FROM " + DBtable`
    

    ## Execute the query
    
      mycursor.execute(query)
      results = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Following is the for loop that I have written to display the data

script.py contd..

```
    for row in results:     
        print("print data",row)
          <div id="Table2LYR">
            <table id="Table2" style="height: 179px;border-spacing:2px;border-collapse:separate;">
              <tr style="height: auto;">
                <td style="padding: 2px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:187px;" id="Cell5">
                  <p style="line-height: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; max-height: 43px; display: block; width: 187px;">
                  <img height="100" src={6} style="vertical-align: top;"></p>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: rgb(240,234,225);padding: 2px;width:698px;" id="Cell6">
                <h3>{0}</h3>
                <p>
                  Author: {1}<br>
                  Publisher: {2}<br>
                  ISBN:{3} <br>
                  Year: {4} <br>
                  Our price:{5} <br>
                  <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; max-height: 19px; display: block; width: 698px;">Description: {7}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
```

I tried `print("print data",row)` to check data and I can see all the data as console but how do i display those for specific column ?

Whenever i try `Author: {1}` to get first column data it display "Author: {1}" as out put instead of author name.
I was expecting to get the Author name instead of "Author: {1}" text.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with how you are trying to access your data within `row`. You need to index your value out of the `row` variable. If `Author` is in the second spot, then `row[1]` will give you the author value. But this can only happen if you do proper string formatting, like f"Author:{row[1]}"

```
f"<div id=\"Table2LYR\">
            <table id=\"Table2\" style=\"height: 179px;border-spacing:2px;border-collapse:separate;\">
              <tr style=\"height: auto;\">
                <td style=\"padding: 2px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;width:187px;\" id=\"Cell5\">
                  <p style=\"line-height: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; max-height: 43px; display: block; width: 187px;\">
                  <img height=\"100\" src={row[6]} style=\"vertical-align: top;\"></p>
                </td>
                <td style=\"background-color: rgb(240,234,225);padding: 2px;width:698px;\" id=\"Cell6\">
                <h3>{row[0]}</h3>
                <p>
                  Author: {row[1]}<br>
                  Publisher: {row[2]}<br>
                  ISBN:{row[3]} <br>
                  Year: {row[4]} <br>
                  Our price:{row[5]} <br>
                  <p style=\"margin-bottom: 0px; max-height: 19px; display: block; width: 698px;\">Description: {row[7]}</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table> "
```

Comment: I'd personally consider using double quotes (") in the beginning of the f-string and escape the ones inside the HTML, but that's out of scope

Comment: Hi I tried above answer and still it is displaying " Author: {row[1]}" and it says syntax error for '''. also I have updated the question that these all are under  `book_list():` method

Comment: @Snooper_A I tried fixing the formatting errors by escaping all the double quotes, but the same logic applies

Comment: using `f "` it says invalid syntax and i tried to use `print '''` and it is printing same "Author: {row[1]}" no change so far.

Comment: @Snooper_A are you putting a space after the f? It should be `f"..."`.

Comment: More info on [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: No I am using as provided `f"..."`